# Convert a Single View to Tabbed App in iOS/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a few simple apps that are single view.  I want to add a 'Info' tab for some instructions, support details, etc.
What is the easiest way to do this?  Create new Tabbed Apps and copy the existing code in, or edit the current single view apps?  I would prefer if the latter was possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I achieved the same in <5 seconds with the below xCode menu option: Tab Bar Controller.

[image]

I kept my ViewController classes so my main.storyboard looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding more about your current setup your question can't really be answered with any kind of accuracy.

Having said that it's easy enough to add a `UITabBarController` to an existing app, really all you need to do is change the initial view controller.

I presume you haven't tried searching for an example...

Implementing `UITabBarController` in code: http://simplecode.me/2011/12/05/tab-based-ios-apps-uitabbarcontroller/

Storyboards: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards/

Comment: That is incredibly helpful. Thanks for taking the time.